# Should i use <Link> or <NavLink> for navbar items?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is my Navbar Dropdown menu.

```
<div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
<a className="dropdown-item" href="#"><i className="text-secondary ti-reload"></i>Activity</a>
<a className="dropdown-item" href="#"><i className="text-success ti-email"></i>Messages</a>
<a className="dropdown-item" href="#"><i className="text-warning ti-user"></i>Profile</a>
<a className="dropdown-item" href="#"><i className="text-dark ti-layers-alt"></i>Projects <span className="badge badge-info">6</span> </a>
<div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#"><i className="text-info ti-settings"></i>Settings</a>
  <a className="dropdown-item" href="/login" ><i className="text-danger ti-unlock"></i> Login </a>
</div>
```

i want to Open  Login on clicking Login menu item.

i can do like this: Just give href , and point it to the router's path. it still works. Or i can even give navlink or Link.
Which is the better way to do this.
can i simply say href={mypathname} . Because even that is working.

```
<a className="dropdown-item" href="/login" ><i className="text-danger ti-unlock"></i> Login </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use styling into your link then you can use NavLink otherwise use Link.

Comment: what if i just give an href="/login" , will it be ohk , because i want to re render the entire login component.

Comment: do you want to use href with your anchor tag(<a>)? if so you still can use but it will reload the page and will not be effected as reactjs router .

Comment: actually i am toggling the navigation bar , with a Higher Order Component , which calls a function to check if the Component is Login , remove the Navbar and sidebar component from login , as i dont want the navbar and sidebar component to be visible when the login component is visible. If i use <Link> to do it , the checking does not happen from the HOC component. but if i use <a> tag it does. Thanks for the help anyway :)